# Parsing multiple row from json info in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

My json stiring is:

{

```
"locations" :[
       {                
        id = 0;
        lat = "41.653048";
        long = "-0.880677";
        name = "LIMPIA";
       },
       {
        id = 1;
        lat = "41.653048";
        long = "-0.890677";
        name = "LIMPIA2";
       }
  ]
```

}

Using:

```
NSDictionary * root = [datos_string1 JSONValue];
NSArray *bares = (NSArray *) [root objectForKey:@"locations"];  

   for (NSArray * row in bares) {
    NSString *barName1 = [bares valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@",barName1);
    }
```

I obtain from NSlog , twice otput
(
    LIMPIA,
    LIMPIA2
)

So somthing is wrong. I need to estract di single value parameter (lat, lon and nombre) for each item (in order to use in a mapkit app). Could you help me?

Comment: This is not valid JSON, seems like it's rather an old NeXTSTEP-formatted PLIST...

Comment: tx! Sorry, but Iwas wrong. I just edit the JSON. I have the problen in parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to estract di single value parameter (lat, lon and nombre) for each item (in order to use in a mapkit app)

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to access each value in each dictionary in the `locations` array, is that right?

In order to access each value (if that is indeed your question), this should work:

```
NSDictionary *root = [datos_string1 JSONValue];
NSArray *bares = (NSArray *)[root objectForKey:@"locations"];  

// Each item in the array is a dictionary, not an NSArray
for (NSDictionary *dict in bares) {
    // Loop over keys
    for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"dict[%@] == %@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnks! your metod allows to access each value en order. it'is useful.